# How to get string data of one column as an array data from data base

Tags: java, android, arrays

In an app I have used 7 checkboxes to get the days name from user and I am storing those name in an array based on selected checkboxes and then converting them to String data and store in database now I want to get the data back as an array only.
for eg:

```
days={"Mon","Tue","Wed","Sat"}
```

And now the database column has this value as: [Mon,Tue,Wed,Sat] which is stored as a String.
I can get this string back but how to convert it back to array so that i can compare the array data with current day like if today is Mon so i can find out which column has Mon.

Please help me out as I don't know what to search any related link or post or any suggestions how to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: for day of week,``enum`` is a better choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. Though, your values should not have "," in them.

```
String[] strs = new String[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" };

String joined = Arrays.toString( strs );

String joinedMinusBrackets = joined.substring( 1, joined.length() - 1);

// String.split()
String[] resplit = joinedMinusBrackets.split( ", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699963/storing-result-set-into-an-array))

or you convert the resultset into an array using getArray() method, [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)