# how to solve operation is not allowed for result set type FORWARD_ONLY?

Tags: java, resultset, hana

I have this method in a class trying to read from a DB in HANA to insert in oracle:

```
private void  selectZ_ITEM_MASTER() {
    //System.out.println("entre al select");
   try {
       Statement stmt;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
       ds.setDriverClassName(getHec_driver());
       ds.setUrl(getHec_url());
       ds.setUsername(getHec_usuario());
       ds.setPassword(getHec_clave());
       ds.setMaxActive(-1);

       Connection con = ds.getConnection();   
       stmt = con.createStatement(

            ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            String query  = "SELECT ";
                   query += "MARA.MANDT, "; 
                   query += "MARC.WERKS, "; 
                   query += "MARA.MATNR, "; 
                   query += "MAKT.MAKTX, "; 
                   query += "MAKT.MAKTG, "; 
                   query += "MARA.MATKL, "; 
                   query += "T023T.WGBEZ, "; 
                   query += "T023T.WGBEZ60, "; 
                   query += "MARA.BRGEW, "; 
                   query += "MARA.NTGEW, "; 
                   query += "MARA.GEWEI, "; 
                   query += "MARA.MEINS, "; 
                   query += "MARA.SPART, "; 
                   query += "TSPAT.VTEXT ";
                   query += "FROM ";
                   query += "SAPR3P.MARA MARA LEFT OUTER JOIN SAPR3P.MAKT MAKT ON MARA.MANDT = MAKT.MANDT AND ";
                   query += "                                                             MARA.MATNR = MAKT.MATNR ";
                   query += "                     LEFT OUTER JOIN SAPR3P.T023T T023T ON MARA.MANDT = T023T.MANDT AND ";
                   query += "                                                               MARA.MATKL = T023T.MATKL AND ";
                   query += "                                                               T023T.SPRAS = 'S' ";
                   query += "                     LEFT OUTER JOIN SAPR3P.TSPAT TSPAT ON MARA.MANDT = TSPAT.MANDT AND "; 
                   query += "                                                               MARA.SPART = TSPAT.SPART AND ";
                   query += "                                                               TSPAT.SPRAS = 'S' ";
                   query += "                     LEFT OUTER JOIN SAPR3P.MARC MARC ON MARA.MANDT = MARC.MANDT AND "; 
                   query += "                                                             MARA.MATNR = MARC.MATNR ";                       
                   query += "WHERE "; 
                   query += "MARA.MANDT = '100' ";
                   //query += "AND MARC.WERKS IN ('3000') ";
                   //query += "AND MARA.MATNR IN ('000000004030005209','000000004030005215')";
                   query += "AND MARC.WERKS IN ('1000','2000') ";
                   query += "AND MARA.MATNR BETWEEN '000000001000000152' AND '000000001000000152' ";
                   query += "ORDER BY ";
                   query += "MARA.MANDT, MARC.WERKS, ";
                   query += "MARA.MATNR ";

                   //System.out.println(query);

      try{
       rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
       rows = 1;
        rs.last();
        rows = rs.getRow();
       System.out.println("Cantidad de Registros:" + rows);

       ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
       columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
       System.out.println("Cantidad de Columnas:" +columns);
       arr = new String[rows][columns];

       int i = 0;
        rs.beforeFirst();
       while (rs.next()){
           for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            arr [i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);
            i++;


          }
               } catch (SQLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               insertLog("Z_ITEM_MASTER VEN: " + e.getMessage(),"error", "Z_ITEM_MASTER VEN");
           }
       stmt.close();
       con.close();
       rs.close();

   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       msj  = e.getMessage();
       insertLog("Z_ITEM_MASTER VEN: " + e.getMessage(),"error", "Z_ITEM_MASTER VEN");
   }
}
```

I was getting an error with use CONCUR_READ_ONLY, CONCUR_UPDATABLE and I managed to solved it by researching about Invalid argument result Set Concurrency, but now I'm having another issue and I'm kind of stuck. this is the error msg:

```
 com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: The operation is not allowed for result set type FORWARD_ONLY.
at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.createException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:345)
at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.generateSQLException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:113)
at com.sap.db.jdbc.ResultSetSapDB.assertNotForwardOnly(ResultSetSapDB.java:2760)
at com.sap.db.jdbc.ResultSetSapDB.last(ResultSetSapDB.java:592)
at com.sap.db.jdbc.trace.ResultSet.last(ResultSet.java:972)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.last(DelegatingResultSet.java:367)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.last(DelegatingResultSet.java:367)
at org.inverpaca.integracion.Integracion.selectZ_ITEM_MASTER(Integracion.java:145)
at org.inverpaca.integracion.Integracion.insertDatos(Integracion.java:207)
at org.inverpaca.integracion.Integracion.main(Integracion.java:287)
```

can someone help me?

some forums refer to this problems having something to do with the statements setting to the correct result set or something like that.

Comment: Looks like `rs.last()` is [not allowed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#last()) for that type of ResultSet.  Iteration can only go forward **once**, and not jump around (such as to the last record).

Comment: I believe the issue is the `rs.beforeFirst()` _after_ moving to the last row.  You cannot scroll backwards in a `FORWARD_ONLY` result set.

Comment: Is there a work around this? i noticed it like 10 mins ago while debugging that rs.last(); was the problem, and when i tried to make it insensitive y told me to use foward_only again... how can i add results? i was thinking of aplying a list but that means changing almost the hole method.

Answer (score 0):

With the forward-only cursor, you cannot jump to the end to get the number of records and then jump back to iterate through the result set.

You seem to use this information only to size the array that you want to put the result set into. There are better ways to do that, e.g. [Storing Result set into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699963/storing-result-set-into-an-array).

Besides that, you might want to check with your license teams, whether or not you are actually licensed to access the SAP data like this. Direct database access on the base tables of the data model comes with many restrictions as you by-pass the whole application level security model.