# SQL Query result to Java Array

Tags: java

I want to read the query result in to array and want to check the array in if condition.
Query in returns

```
SELECT COLUMN
 FROM Table;
OUT PUT:
A
B
C
D
F
```

Want to store the above result in array in java and use in the if condition.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Result set into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699963/storing-result-set-into-an-array)

Comment: In case you were wondering: an “answer” your question received a few hours ago was not meant to answer your question. It was copied from a site that uses machine-learning to generate “plausible looking” answers, and the person that copied that to your question thought that actually posting them here would be funny. While we don’t outright *hate* fun here at Stack Overflow, we do strongly dislike jokes at the expense of others, so we removed that answer as well as the account that posted it. I’m sorry that they picked your question as their target!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would basically go something like this:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(yourSQLQueryString); // Get your ResultSet from Database

rs.last();                  // Place the record pointer onto the last row
int counter = res.getRow(); // Get the row number (there's your count)
rs.first();                 // Place the record pointer onto the first row for the while loop
String[] myArray = new String[counter]; // Declare and Initialize your array

counter = 0; // Reset counter to 0 so as to act as a Index incrementer
// Iterate through the ResultSet and fill Array
while (rs.next()) {
    myArray[counter] = rs.getString(columnNumber_OR_ColumnNameString); 
    counter++;
}

// See what's in Array...
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(myArray[i]);
}
```

You can take care of handling Exceptions.